# Have Excel VBA wait for PowerQuery data refresh to continue

Tags: excel, vba, wait

My scenario : I have a few data tables pulled via PowerQuery that I wanted to have automatically refresh the data, save, and close. I had a task scheduler run these every day at 1 AM. The problem was that Excel VBA doesn't wait for the PowerQuery to update before it goes to the next step (save).

There are a LOT of blogs about this, I didn't find any answer - but it led me to something that worked for me! I'm not proud of the code but here it is:

```
     Public Sub DataRefresh()

DisplayAlerts = False

For Each objConnection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    'Get current background-refresh value
    bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery

    'Temporarily disable background-refresh
    objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False

    'Refresh this connection
    objConnection.Refresh

    'Set background-refresh value back to original value
    objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
Next

Workbooks("DA List.xlsm").Model.Refresh
DoEvents

For i = 1 To 100000
Worksheets("DA List").Range("G1") = i
Next i
DoEvents

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.Quit

End Sub
```

I think this works because I gave excel something to do other than the data refresh, and the extra lines between DoEvents and my next step seemed to make VBA finally figure out what I was intending.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: You should post what worked for you as an answer so that it shows up in search results as a problem with a solution. (Adding [Solved] in the title is not the SO way). Also, there is quite a bit of blank space in your code block that could be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Public Sub DataRefresh()

DisplayAlerts = False

For Each objConnection In ThisWorkbook.Connections
'Get current background-refresh value
bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery

'Temporarily disable background-refresh
objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False

'Refresh this connection
objConnection.Refresh

'Set background-refresh value back to original value
objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
Next

Workbooks("DA List.xlsm").Model.Refresh
DoEvents

For i = 1 To 100000
Worksheets("DA List").Range("G1") = i
Next i
DoEvents

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.Quit

End Sub
```